# Conditionally replace matrix upper-triangle elements with lower-triangle

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to replace the upper triangle of a matrix with the lower triangle of the matrix when the lower triangle entries are equal to a given value. For example, I have the following matrix:

```
0 0 0 
1 0 0 
2 1 0
```

I need to copy all lower triangle entries that are equal to 1 to the upper triangle. The result should be:

```
0 1 0 
1 0 1 
2 1 0
```

I tried using:

```
library(gdata)

z <- matrix(c(0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
upperTriangle(z) <- t(lowerTriangle(z)[lowerTriangle(z)==1])
```

But this replace the entire upper triangle with 1. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `z+ t(z*(z==1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
z <- matrix(c(0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
z[upper.tri(z) & t(z) == 1] = 1
```

works for me.

Note: your upperTriangel and lowerTriangle do not appear to be part of base.  You might want to indicate which package they are from.